# magnitude of two vectors

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

[image]

How would I find the crossproduct if all I have is the point values?

Comment: It's not asking for the cross-product, it's asking for the magnitude only. I'd guess that your book or notes contain a formula relating this with $|u|$ and $|v|$.

Comment: @T.Bongers, it's asking for both (*vide* the multiple choice options).  But the formulation gives both magnitudes and *directions* ("north" and "northeast") of **u** and **v**.

Comment: How would I calculate the angle between the two?

Comment: @user3819671: It's the angle between "north" and "northeast". You don't _calculate_ that; you're assumed to _know_ how compass directions work.

Answer (score 1):

$|\textbf{u}\times \textbf{v}|=|\textbf{u}||\textbf{v}|\sin\theta$

where $\theta$ is the angle between them.

Comment: how would I calculate the angle?

Comment: You know the angle between north and east, which is 90 degrees. You also know that northeast is halfway between north and east, so the angle must be 45 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

$|u×v|=|u||v|sinθ$
where $θ=\pi/4$ is the angle between North and North East.

Comment: so 5 * 10 * sin pi/4?

Comment: yes, that is exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're told you're looking *down* at a *map* and asked for the *direction* in which the cross product points suggests converting the descriptions of the two vectors into $x$, $y$, and $z$ coordinates of a triplet in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  The appropriate interpretation is

$$u=(0,5,0)\qquad\text{and}\qquad v=(\sqrt{5/2},\sqrt{5/2},0)$$

Can you take it from here?

(One hint:  If you know the right-hand rule, you can find the direction without calculating anything.)

Comment: Still a bit lost, I am quite confused :/ I'll keep trying to understand more about this topic in my textbook

Comment: @user3819671, try drawing a picture.  The problem specifies two arrows emanating from the origin.  One points due north, the other one to the northeast.